# Using vuejs components in vue typescript project

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-class-components

I want to use vue-simple-spinner in my project, but when I import it I get the following error:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue-simple-spinner'. 
'c:/Users/Korisnik/Desktop/projects/typescript-chord-app/node_modules/vue- 
simple-spinner/dist/vue-simple-spinner.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm install @types/vue-simple-spinner` if it exists or add a new 
declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'vue-simple-spinner';`
```

I created `shims-spinner.d.ts` file:

```
declare module 'vue-simple-spinner' {
  import Spinner from 'vue-simple-spinner';
  export default Spinner;
}
```

but then I get `Circular definition of import alias 'Spinner'`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Don't declare your module with the same name as the module you're importing from?

Comment: @RoyJ That helps, but I still get the first error, only now in `shims-spinner.d.ts`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to import and render the `Spinner` module, you should be able to do so by placing:

```
declare module 'vue-simple-spinner' {
  const spinner: any;
  export default spinner;
 }
```

In your `shims.d.ts`.

If you want to use a more complex type (which I don't think has any use in this case, since you're only importing the Spinner to render it in html) you can replace the `any` typing with anything that makes sense.